# How to delete an object of a polymorphic class type that has no virtual destructor

Tags: c++, inheritance, destructor

I am getting the following error when I try to compile some code from a Third-party SDK.

```
*Description    Resource    Path    Location    Type
deleting object of polymorphic class type ‘Vendor_sys::VendorCode’ which has non-virtual destructor might cause undefined behaviour [-Werror=delete-non-virtual-dtor]   PnServer.cpp    /PCounter   line 467    C/C++ Problem*
```

---

I do not know if its possible to satisfy this condition with only partial knowledge of the Vendor's SDK, where most of the heavy lifting is done in a dll or library object.

My build environment is Eclipse Juno with gpp.

I searched in Google for the error message and did not find any instances of this error.

So, if I cannot modify the black box part of the vendor code, what are my options?

Here is the code that is failing during the make process:

```
delete pData->unit;
```

Comment: So the class is meant to be inherited from, but doesn't have a virtual destructor? I'd complain to whoever made that library.

Comment: The warning is a little mild. Deleting an object of a derived type through a pointer to a base type that doesn't have a virtual destructor results in undefined behavior. No "might" about it.

Comment: @PeteBecker At least g++ 4.8 issues this warning, even if I delete through a pointer to the derived class. This would be safe (AFAIK), so the "might" is also wrong here (the warning is not supposed to be generated at all). I guess g++ can't distinguish the two cases.

Comment: @PeterBecker In my case, it could of course be a further derived class (in which case the warning is correct), but this case can never (IMHO) be excluded.

Answer (score -5, accepted):

Actually, I removed the -Werror switch from the compile and the program compiled.

Now, the messages are just warnings.

I will send a bug report to the vendor.

Comment: Not the correct way according to me, you should not change your compilation flags just so that your code compiles unless there is no other way

Answer (score 18):

Bad news, I am afraid. You should not use that class as a base class. Too many constraints and pitfalls. You might get away with it, but why risk it? File a bug report with the library vendor.

If you do not need polymorphic pointers, include an object of that type in your class, and delegate the member functions you wanted to inherit.

```
class my_class {
private:
    evil_class evil;
public:
    virtual ~my_class() {/* stuff */}
    virtual int member() { return evil.member(); }
};
```

Comment: Right way to do so, this should have been marked as answer

Answer (score 13):

Well it's a bug in the third-party SDK. Any class that is used as a base class should have a virtual destructor. Otherwise, when you delete a pointer to the base of a derived class instance, the derived class's destructor won't be called.

One way around it is to not delete pointers to the base. Instead, use dynamic_cast to get a pointer to the derived class (this might be inconvenient if there are many classes derived from that base).

Answer (score 9):

In this scenario you need to add virtual destructor to your class rather than removing compilation flag from here.

eg. for class `Myclass` this error is coming then add

```
virtual ~Myclass(){}
```

Try this soultion, it will work fine.

Answer (score 4):

This warning is produced when the base class has virtual member functions but no virtual dtor. This is a bug. If you don't have the code, then there's nothing you can do other than making sure you're manually de-allocating any resources in your subclass. Like in a custom `cleanup()` member function that you make sure to call manually before deleting the object.

Another option is to `static_cast` it to the correct class. Note that `dynamic_cast` (which incurs runtime overhead and requires RTTI) is not needed. The compiler can derive the type relationship just fine at compile time in this case.

Of course, if the object is deleted somewhere else that's not part of you code, then you're out of luck. In that case, make sure your subclass doesn't allocate anything. That way it's not possible to leak even when the destructor isn't being called.

Comment: Doesn't matter whether the base type has virtual functions; if the base type doesn't have a virtual destructor, deleting an object of a derived type through a pointer to base has undefined behavior. Of course, having no virtual functions means it's not likely that anyone will be fiddling with pointers to the base type.

Comment: @PeteBecker GCC doesn't give the warning when there are no virtual functions. The problem is still there, but there's no warning. C++ before the 2011 standard didn't have the `final` keyword, so it is assumed that classes without virtual functions are not supposed to be inherited from. If that were the case, that would be the OPs mistake. In this case, it's the SDK's mistake. Just wanted to point that out.

Comment: "it is assumed" hides a great deal of vagueness. <g> There are several classes in the C++ standard that don't have virtual functions but are intended to be used as base classes. The template class `iterator`, for example, provides a handful of typedefs for its derived types. That's not a problem so long as you don't try to delete an object of a derived type through a pointer to iterator. Some warnings are about a compiler writer's notion that I'm not smart enough to use a language feature that's well defined and clearly meaningful.

Comment: I am not creating any subclasses from the class in question.

Answer (score 3):

You cannot safely use a pointer to the base class, unless it has a virtual destructor declared on the base class.  Since this is a vendor library, you can not add the virtual destructor needed.

If the library itself does not create subclasses of this object, you may be able to get the effect you need by declaring a subclass for this object and use that object as a base class.

```
class NotGoodBase {
 ~NotGoodBase(); // Non-virtual destructor.  Possibly added by compiler.
};

class UseThisAsBase : public NotGoodBase {
 virtual ~UseThisAsBase(); // Virtual destructor.
};
```

You should be able to use pointers of type UseThisAsBase anywhere that you could use NotGoodBase, except places where you need to have an LValue of type NotGoodBase, such as an assignment or when passing a variable by reference.

Comment: Actually, he might be able to add the virtual destructor in the header file. Hack, hack, kluge. Depends on whether one is declared there but not defined there.