# How to delete an object of derived class that has no dstructor

Tags: c++, compiler-warnings, derived-class

Given this program:

```
struct Base
{
  virtual void f() {}
};

struct Derived:public Base
{
};

int main()
{
  Derived* c = new Derived;
  delete c;
}
```

gcc-4.4 -Wall is fine but gcc-5.2 -Wall gives warning: deleting object of polymorphic class type 'Derived' which has non-virtual destructor might cause undefined behaviour [-Wdelete-non-virtual-dtor]

I saw [the discussion on deleting a base pointer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12994920/how-to-delete-an-object-of-a-polymorphic-class-type-that-has-no-virtual-destruct) but in my case it's the derived object. I think it's a gcc bug, but apparently [GNU doesn't think so](https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=53596). Is there anyway to get rid of the warning without changing the base class definition?

Comment: The code is correct as-is; you could ignore the warning.

Answer (score 3):

GCC has every right to emit that warning. Why? Because unless you declare that `Derived` is `final`, it's entirely possible for someone to create a `MoreDerived` type that is derived from `Derived`. At which point, your deletion of a `Derived` pointer can very much be invalid.

Adding a `virtual` destructor to `Base` has no real downsides. Yes, the destructor will be a virtual call. But that's hardly going to be a performance bottleneck.

Comment: Adding "final" in the Derived class would solve the issue. I can't change the Base class as it's provided by vendor. Well, I guess I can change .h but not .so. A couple of off-topic but related questions: 1. if there's no ~Base(), can I safely add "virtual ~Base() {}"?  2. If there is non-virtual dtor in Base, can I safely add virtual?

Comment: your vendor really should fix this, it is a big no-no in c++ and a common job interview question,

Comment: No, the warning is wrong. The type of the pointee is `Derived`, regardless of whether there is a `MoreDerived` type, and there's no problem deleting it in the context shown. Granted, in a different context, the warning would be right, but that's not the case here.

Comment: @PeteBecker: And how would the compiler know that? Why should the compiler bother to check the over-simplified cases like this, where the object is allocated right before being destroyed?

Comment: @NicolBolas - <shrug>. The warning is wrong, and there is no action needed to "fix" it. The fact that the compiler can't sensibly detect this doesn't change that. Granted, this is a very simplified case, but my point is simply that the code as written is just fine; the warning is spurious, and the compiler does not "have every right to emit that warning".

Comment: @PeteBecker: Compilers emit warnings for code that is "just fine" all the time. That's what warnings are *for*: to warn you that, while the code you've written is legal C++, it may not be doing what you wanted it to. It's no different from warning on `if(x = 4)`. Well, there is a difference in that there's a common convention for shutting the compiler up in that case.

Comment: @NicolBolas - **This code** has well-defined behavior and it does **exactly what it's intended to do**: it deletes the object that was created in the preceding line. There is **nothing wrong with it**. That's not at all the same as `if(x = 4)`, which is often the result of a typo, so may well be a mistake.

Comment: @PeteBecker: "*which is often the result of a typo*" So is not adding a virtual destructor. That is a common mistake too, as exemplified here. The library that defined `Base` *ought* to have provided one. You can construct a scenario where assignment in an `if` is "exactly what it's intended to do" and "has well-defined behavior". Where "there is nothing wrong with it".

Comment: @NicolBolas - there is no mistake here, except in your implicit application of unspecified coding guidelines. What in the world makes you think that the definition of `Base` ought to have a virtual destructor? That's a **design decision** that cannot be based on the minimal amount of information presented here. The rule is that if a class is intended to be derived from **and** derived objects will be deleted through pointers to the base type, then the base type should have a virtual destructor. There's nothing here to indicate that that rule applies.

Comment: @PeteBecker: "*What in the world makes you think that the definition of `Base` ought to have a virtual destructor?*" Because it has declared a `virtual` function. That implies the desire for a user to both derive from it *and* to use the derived class as though it were a `Base`. The later becomes exceedingly dangerous without a proper `virtual` destructor. This is standard procedure in C++; pretty much all the books, online resources, etc, say that if you have a `virtual` function in a base class, you ought to have a `virtual` destructor too. Hence the warning.

Comment: Adding a virtual destructor **would not change what this code does**. So the warning is wrong. Yes, some people use style guides as blunt instruments without understanding their implications. Others try to understand the reasons behind the guidelines and apply them sensibly. Deriving from a type that does not have a virtual destructor is not automatically a mistake. There are quite a few classes in the C++ standard, for example, that are intended to be used as base classes but do not have virtual destructors. That was a deliberate decision, and a correct one.

Comment: @PeteBecker: "*Deriving from a type that does not have a virtual destructor is not automatically a mistake.*" I didn't say it was. It is however a mistake to have a type that has a `virtual` function that doesn't have a `virtual` destructor. I know of no cases in the C++ standard that does this.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/117485/discussion-between-nicol-bolas-and-pete-becker).

Answer (score 2):

Adding `virtual ~Base() {}` to Base would fix the warning.

So would adding `final` to Derived.

```
class Derived final : public Base
{
    ...
};
```

And so would adding a virtual destructor to Derived.

```
class Derived : public Base
{
public:
    virtual ~Derived() {}

    ...
};
```

Also, if you don't plan on using Derived polymorphically, you could inherit it privately. This doesn't prevent the warning, but you could never assign a Derived pointer to a Base pointer, and thus could never delete a Derived via a Base pointer.

```
class Derived : private Base
{
    ...
};
```

Comment: I'm aware that the code is 100% legal, works as intended, and that there is no undefined behavior. At the same time, sometimes people want to get rid of all warnings in their code. Since GCC likely won't change the warning, some other solution is needed.

Comment: Yes, sorry. Perseveration from the other answer. Yours is simply a direct answer to the question, explaining how to get rid of the warning. I've deleted my comment.

Answer (score 0):

The C++ Standard, [expr.delete], paragraph 3 [ISO/IEC 14882-2014], states the following:

In the first alternative (delete object), if the static type of the object to be deleted is different from its dynamic type, the static type shall be a base class of the dynamic type of the object to be deleted and the static type shall have a virtual destructor or the behavior is undefined. In the second alternative (delete array) if the dynamic type of the object to be deleted differs from its static type, the behavior is undefined.

Do not delete an object of derived class type through a pointer to its base class type that has a non-virtual destructor. Instead, the base class should be defined with a virtual destructor. Deleting an object through a pointer to a type without a virtual destructor results in undefined behavior.
In this compliant solution, the destructor for Base has an explicitly declared virtual destructor, ensuring that the polymorphic delete operation results in well-defined behavior.

```
struct Base {
  virtual ~Base() = default;
  virtual void f();
};

struct Derived : Base {};

void f() {
  Base *b = new Derived();
  // ...
  delete b;
}
```

You can find more information, if use this link: https://wiki.sei.cmu.edu/confluence/display/cplusplus/OOP52-CPP.+Do+not+delete+a+polymorphic+object+without+a+virtual+destructor